# Optimizing query that subselects data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query that is taking several minutes to run and I'm trying to see if there is a way to optimize it, or if it just needs to be broken into different queries.

Without showing the whole monster, the essence is:

```
SELECT
u.id,
u.email,
(select count(*) from photos where u.id = user_id) as num_of_photos,
(select count(*) from activity_log where type = 1 and u.id = user_id) as num_logins,
(select count(*) from activity_log where type = 4 and u.id = user_id) as num_help_views,
(select count(*) from activity_log) as activity_rating
FROM
user as u
ORDER BY activity_rating DESC
```

There are about 20 sub-selects pulling different pieces of data about each user, which ultimately is output to a CSV report.

There's only a couple thousand users in the DB so far and the query is impractical.  Are there any optimizations that can be made?

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. **My guess: no indexes on activity_log and other subtables.**

Comment: @AndyLester You're right - it was a missing index causing most of the hold-up.  Once I added the index, it dropped from 62.1 seconds to 0.00591 seconds.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  Glad it worked.  I made it an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: no indexes on activity_log and other subtables.